# ASP.NET OWIN self hosting console window couldn't start dynamically from a normal ASP.NET Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, self-hosting

I needed to start my OWIN self hosting console application, based on demand. This demand is deciding inside a separate ASP.NET Web API, which is normally hosted under IIS express of VS in a debug mode. But I couldn't prompt the command window from inside this decision making ASP.NET Web API even though no errors received. Below is my testing code to just invoke a command prompt, directly written inside my decision making Web API Controller.

```
 using (Process p = new Process())
                {
                    // set start info
                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
                    {
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        WorkingDirectory = @"d:\"
                    };
                    // event handlers for output & error
                    p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
                    p.ErrorDataReceived += p_ErrorDataReceived;

                    // start process
                    p.Start();
                    // send command to its input
                    p.StandardInput.Write("dir" + p.StandardInput.NewLine);
                    //wait
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
```

All applications are in same machine. I didn't get any output as of above code running under an ASP.NET MVC controller event hough same code giving me an expected command window if run under a console application.

```
Is there any restriction to prompt command window under an ASP.NET Web API context?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to prompt command by removing "RedirectStandardInput" as below.

```
try
  {
                    using (Process p = new Process())
                    {
                        // set start info
                        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
                        {
                            // RedirectStandardInput = true,
                            // UseShellExecute = false,
                            //WorkingDirectory = root + @"\Test"
                        };

                        // start process
                        p.Start();
                        p.WaitForExit();
                        p.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
```

Keeping this thread open as if anyone comes with an answer for prompting command for a case of RedirectStandardInput = true too